# « Vous vous êtes trempé les pieds dans l’eau »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique

On dit: Vous vous êtes trempés dans l’eau.
Dit-on: Vous vous êtes trempé les pieds dans l’eau?

Est-ce que ce verbe peut être construit à la forme pronominale et appeler un complément d’objet direct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui, il est tout à fait possible d'avoir un complément d'objet direct avec un verbe à la forme pronominale.

- Vous vous êtes trempé les pieds dans l'eau.
- Elle s'est mis la tête sous l'eau.
- Il s'est lavé les mains dans le lavabo.
- Ces autruches ne se sont pas mis la tête dans le sable.

C'est l'occasion de rappeler l'accord du participe passé avec les verbes pronominaux : le participe passé ne s'accorde pas lorsque le C.O.D. suit le verbe.
Et c'est correct dans la question.
Il s'accorde avec son C.O.D en genre et en nombre lorsque le C.O.D. précède le verbe.

- Les pieds qu'ils se sont trempés dans l'eau.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129054/discussion-on-answer-by-none-vous-vous-etes-trempe-les-pieds-dans-leau).